# How to make a texture blend into the specular

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

does anybody know how to make something like this:

[image]

As you can see the procedural texture changes to create a blending-like effect. Or does anybody know what that is called so I can look it up myself?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're looking for. In the picture, the Material has a certain degree of Specularity, and the Diffuse texture gets a bit swallowed up by the specular highlight, towards the centre, but that happens automatically without you having to do anything.

Comment: @Susan, perhaps, but anyway let say that he's right about what's happening. The part with spots can easily be done with a mix of Noise and Voronoi, but it's harder to find a nice way to make what he asks.

Comment: @moonboots OK. I don't think I've quite understood the question, or else I need to put my glasses on.

Comment: It's alright, I think I was able to replicate that: https://gyazo.com/296555af950e11c3e79c8235fdef97bc Thank you anyway!